# SQLite Performing Between on TEXT Data types

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I made quite a silly mistake in implementing my SQLite database with a TEXT datatype for the date in the form of YYYY-mm-dd.

Is there anyway to perform BETWEEN operations on text which is in the form of a date?

For example,

```
String sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
selectionArgs = new String[] {"2017-01-07","2017-01-01"};
database.rawQuery(sql,selectionArgs);
```

I'm in an android environment.

Any recommendations on what I could do if I really need to get dates with BETWEEN?

Comment: look here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm date time format in android is actually stored in text format and you can perform all sql operations on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stored your dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, they should still sort correctly even as text.  So, I would expect your current query to actually work as you have it right now.

The query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-07'
```

is identical to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date >= '2017-01-01' AND column_date <= '2017-01-07'
```